How was Rabbi Akiva’s wish to fulfill the commandment of ״בכל נפשך״ actually fulfilled?
The Gemara (Berachos 61b) tells the story of Rabbi Akiva, who was killed for teaching Torah, and before he was killed, he told his students that he was now finally able to fulfill the commandment of ״בכל נפשך״ - “with all your soul” (Devarim 6:5).
My question is: isn’t that verse talking about giving up your life not to serve Avodah Zarah (see Yoma 82a)? So how was Rabbi Akiva’s wish fulfilled if he was being killed for teaching Torah - not for refusing to serve Avodah Zarah?

When the Gemara says the verse is about avodah Zara, must it have no other meaning?

The general mitzvah (Brachos 9:5) is to love Hashem even when he takes your life.

@Yø-cRo it seems from Tosafos on Kesubos 33b ד״ה אלמלי נגדוה, that Rabbi Akiva was referring to the Mitzvah of giving up one’s life for the sake of Torah/Mitzvos.

The question is based on a false assumption that the logic of Gemara is binary. But it is not. Loving Hashem to a degree that one gives one's life is not equivalent by far to giving one's life to avoid serving idols (contra-negative). The former is a much more difficult than the later as it requires active actions, while the latter is passive. Judaism is not math.

See Berakhot 61b and Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah 5:7. L’choira they’re talking about giving up one’s life for Torah, not specifically with regard to Avodah Zara
